# Why does Nibabel change the size of my file?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, nibabel

I am working with images in the format nii.gz. Therefore, I am using [nibabel](http://nipy.org/nibabel/) in order to open them. The problem is that when I open the images, transform them to numpy arrays and convert them back to Nifti format, the output size is changed. The sequence is:

```
nifti_image = nib.load('/my_path_to_image/image.nii.gz')
np_img = ct_images.get_fdata()
nifti_final = nib.Nifti1Image(data, affine=np.eye(4)) # Convert them to nifti
nib.save(nifti_final , 'image.nii.gz')
```

The initial file is `~45 MB`, after running the code above, the image is `~65 MB`. I know that the original images are 16-bit encoded. My initial theory was that when transforming to numpy array, they were encoded as `64-bit` which is indeed the case. So I tried the following:

```
nifti_image = nib.load('/my_path_to_image/image.nii.gz')
np_img = ct_images.get_fdata()
np_img = np_img.astype(numpy.float16, copy=False)
nifti_final = nib.Nifti1Image(data, affine=np.eye(4)) # Convert them to nifti
nib.save(nifti_final , 'image.nii.gz')
```

However, the ouput is still the same size `~65MB`. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the original nifti affine and header information to the output nifti. E.g., in your case:

```
nifti_final = nib.Nifti1Image(data, nifti_image.affine, nifti_image.header)
```